# Minecraft free op server help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

So, I'm making a free op minecraft server. I don't want everyone being able to stop the server or ban anyone, so should I set the op level to 2?
SuperOP will be able to ban, so obviously level 3.
Owner will be level 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sets the default permission level for ops when using /op. All levels inherit abilities and commands from levels before them.
    1 - Ops can bypass spawn protection.
    2 - Ops can use all singleplayer cheats commands (except /publish, as it is not on servers; along with /debug) and use command blocks. Command blocks and Realms operators/owners have this level.
    3 - Ops can use most multiplayer-exclusive commands (all except level 4 commands).
    4 - Ops can use all commands including /stop, /save-all, /save-on, and /save-off.
```

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties)